# My new form closes no matter which button I click

Tags: c#, forms, dialog, windows

My Form1 opens a new form when "Show Images" is clicked. When the MW3Images comes up, it closes whether I click on "Next", "Previous" or "Close". I have set the "cancel button" option to use the "Close" button, but changing it makes no difference.
Here is my source code for the "Show Images" button:

```
   private void showImages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MW3Images MW3Images = new MW3Images();
        MW3Images.ShowDialog();
        if (MW3Images.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
            MW3Images.Close();
    }
```

And for the MW3Images form:

```
   public MW3Images()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        Controls.Add(pictureBox1);

        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.boxart;

        next.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        previous.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        imagesQuit.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
    private void Images_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
    private void imagesQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
    private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
    private void previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

I had several if statements under "Next" and "Previous", but their presence did not affect the form closing.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `MW3Images` is local to your event `showImages_Click`, It only exists in the scope of that event, so I believe when you come out of that event, it gets closed.

Comment: Sounds like you have a close called somewhere that executes every time and not after you only click quit.

Comment: one thing you should do is move `your` code out of the constructor and put it in the OnInitialized() method.

Comment: CancelButton and AcceptButton works only to define which button will be pressed if your user presses the Escape or Enter keys. The property that closes your form is the DialogResult assigned to you buttons. If you click one of them the corresponding value is assigned to the property DialogResult of the form and the form is closed (hidden for modal)

Comment: I'm still quite new to C# (and all programming), having only started this year. I will try what T McKeown has suggested, see if I can manage. Thanks. @TMcKeown

Comment: add your code in the `OnLoad`

Comment: How? I'm lost with "Constructor" and "OnInitialized()"... @TMcKeown

Comment: in the designer of the form, double click on the form (the form's body area).  It should create an `OnLoad` method for you.

Comment: @user3613679 - Take a look at my answer. I'm pretty sure this doesn't have anything to do with whether your code is in the constructor or not.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I put my code from MW3Images() in Images_Load(..). Makes no difference to the problem of the form closing regardless of the button clicked.

Comment: Shouldn't the correct code be setting the Forms.DialogResult property upon clicking of these buttons?

Comment: are you sure the window is closed?  Have you tried sending a `owner` with the `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @Bobson - I changed the "MW3Images.Close()" to "MW3Images.Dispose()", but it made no difference. Your reply says that regardless of what the set DialogResult is, my new form will close. If that is true, how do I code a button (or two) in the new form, so that the user can scroll through the images manually? Your reply didn't answer my problem, just told me what the reason behind it is.

Comment: @David_Tyrone - Did the edit at the bottom help?  `.Show()` will open a window that isn't tied to the original the way `.ShowDialog()` is.  Or you just don't use `DialogResult` for buttons that aren't supposed to close it.

Comment: I will have to use Show() rather than ShowDialog(). It solves my problem, as far as I can tell. I wanted to give focus to the new form, but its fine if I don't. Thanks for your effort and expertise (especially @Bobson and @TMcKeown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior when you call `.ShowDialog()`.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. The dialog box can be assigned one of the values of the DialogResult enumeration by assigning it to the DialogResult property of a Button on the form or by setting the DialogResult property of the form in code. This value is then returned by this method.

and

> Unlike non-modal forms, the Close method is not called by the .NET Framework when the user clicks the close form button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

In other words, as soon as you set a `DialogResult`, which happens when any button on the form which has such a result is clicked, then the form is hidden and the calling form continues executing its code.

You should either use `.Show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()`, or not use the `DialogResult` property of the buttons on your form.  Instead, if you double-click them in the designer, you'll get an `_Click()` event that you can put your code in.  Inside those functions is where you'd put the code that loaded up the next image - but there's no automatic way to do that.  You'd have to write that yourself.

Comment: You can also set DialogResult to `None` in your click event handler that "Nothing is returned from the dialog box. This means that the modal dialog continues"

Answer (score 1):

Try this, set an owner for the Dialog:

```
MW3Images.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with modifying that collection in the constructor.  That's what Visual Studio does *automatically* inside the `InitializeComponent()` function which is called from the constructor.

Comment: I've had bad experiences when messing with the forms controls in the constructor.  However it may have been because of custom code before the Initialize method was called.